# Safari onClick event on button sporadically not working

Tags: javascript, button, safari, onclick, dom-events

I am using Safari version 8.0.7.  I have a set of buttons that are set up with an inline `onClick` event.  For about 90% of the time, they work perfectly fine, but occasionally the buttons will not fire the event.  If I reload the page, or come back to the page, it will then work.  It's just sporadically does not work.  Is there a known bug that would cause this, or is something in my code causing it?  Here is the relevant code:

The buttons:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php if ($currentPage > 1) : ?>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-default' onClick="progressInstructions(<?=$currentPage;?>, 'back')"><strong><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</strong></button>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <?php if (!isset($lastPage)) : ?>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-default' onClick="progressInstructions(<?=$currentPage;?>, 'forward')"><strong>Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></strong></button>
    <?php else: ?>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-default' id="begin_practice"><strong>Begin Practice <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></strong></button>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The `progressInstructions` code:

```
function progressInstructions(currentPage, direction) {
    $('#page_' + currentPage).hide();
    if (direction == 'forward') {
        $('#page_' + (currentPage + 1)).show();
    } else {
        $('#page_' + (currentPage - 1)).show();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Upon further testing, it seems to only occur when when the pointer is on or near the top border of the button or the top and bottom of the area surrounding the "Continue" or "Back" label. I'm not sure if this helps anything.

Also, I'm using Bootstrap for the page design.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I would check two things to help debug this. First, make sure that the onclick on your button is actually not getting called. Safari shouldn't have any problems with onclick. Easy way to check would be to put a console.log or alert directly on the button:

```
<button onclick="console.log('Hello')"></button>
```

If it actually isn't being called, it most likely is because another element is obscuring it. I'd check the z-axis to make sure it isn't underneath something else

Comment: The console.log fires exactly the same as it would if it was calling the previous onclick function.  I.e., if I click anywhere on the button other than near the top border it fires, but near the top border of the button it does not.  Would this be something caused by a z-axis issue?  How do I check for that?

Comment: try inspecting it in chrome dev tools and testing it momentarily with some extra css rules ploppedin like `z-index: 99999;` and maybe `position: fixed; top: 100px; left: 100px;` to see

Comment: I tried that, and I get the same result.  It's odd, because it only doesn't work along the very top border of the button and the areas just above and below the label on the button.  Very specific, small areas.  Would the use of Bootstraps button tags be something that could cause this?

Comment: the bootstrap buttons should probably be ok, depending on surrounding styles and overrides. I wonder if you could recreate the problem in a plnkr